# How to fix" Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" for IONIC 5

Tags: php, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to use a project from  github:

```
https://github.com/instyo/ionic-login-register-php
```

and i try to insert some info in the forms, I get the error:

> core.js:1449 ERROR Responseheaders: 
>   {
>      "_headers":Map(0),
>      "_normalizedNames":Map(0)
>   }"ok":"falsestatus":0statusText:"""type":3url:"null_body":"ProgressEvent "{
>      "isTrusted":true,
>      "lengthComputable":false,
>      "loaded":0,
>      "total":0,
>      "type":"error",
>      " …"
>   }
>   **proto**: Body
>   defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1449
>   :8080/ionlogin/register.php:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What could this be from?

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

means that the backend that you are trying to connect is not available, making the form request failed. Based on the README of your github link `https://github.com/instyo/ionic-login-register-php`. You need to set up this PHP backend `https://github.com/instyo/php-api-ionic-login` and run it

Comment: what do u exactly mean by set up this php backend i imported the sql and put all the php files in the htdocs of xampp but stil receiving this issue ,do i need to change some things related to domain name in my application ?